# Sort working in main() but not in separate function

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I'm working on a homework problem for C and unix programming, and the teacher told us to write a sort function for an array in C.

I've got sorting working from some for loops in main, but the separate sort function we need doesn't work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int Sort(int arr[], int size){

    int i,j,a;
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
        for(j = i+1; j < size; j++){
            if(arr[i] > arr[j]){
                a = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = a;
            }
        }
    return arr;
    }
}

int main(){
    int a;
    int BAT[40];
    for(int i=0; i < 40; i++){
       BAT[i] = (float)(599)* ( (float)rand() / (float)RAND_MAX );
       printf("%d \n", BAT[i]);
    }
    printf(" the array should now be sorted \n"); 
    //Sort(BAT, 40); THIS IS THE FUNCTION CALL THAT DIDNT SEEM TO WORK SO I COPIED THE SORT OUT OF THE SORT FUNCTION TO TEST

    //THIS IS THE SORT CODE AND WHILE IT IS IN THE MAIN IT WORKS
    for(int i = 0; i < 40; i++){
        for(int j = i+1; j < 40; j++){
            if(BAT[i] > BAT[j]){
                a = BAT[i];
                BAT[i] = BAT[j];
                BAT[j] = a;
            }
        }
    }
    //END OF SORTING TEST
        for(int j=0; j < 40; j++){
            printf("%d \n", BAT[j]);
        }
```

I expect the Sort(BAT, 40) to sort the array which I then try to print but instead nothing seems to occur.

Comment: What is that stray `for` loop in `Sort`? Why `return` is within the loop? you should properly indent your code to sort these things out.

Comment: The function declaration says that `Sort` returns an `int` but you return `int *`. Please try to make a [mcve].

Comment: You're missing a closing brace for the `main()` function, and the return type of `Sort()` is still wrong.

Comment: Fixing the errors mentioned above it seems to work ok: https://ideone.com/TpSvT8

Comment: So I'm very unfamiliar with C I learned you cannot return an array from a function so what I found was that your return type should be int and you return an array which casts it to int* or a pointer?

Comment: Nit, don't use *magic-numbers* in your code (e.g. `40`). If you need a constant, then define a constant for each one needed (e.g. `#define MAXBAT 40`) at the beginning of your code and use the constant in place of the *magic-number*. (e.g. `int BAT[MAXBAT];`) throughout your code. Let's say you need to change your array size to `64` -- look at all the places in your short snippet you must pick through and change. If you define a constant, then only one change is required. You need to call `srand()` before using `rand()`.

Comment: You are passing an array to the function. The array "decays" to a pointer. So your function can be written as `int * Sort(int *arr, int size) {....return arr;}` There's no need to cast. [What is array decaying?](//stackoverflow.com/q/1461432)

Comment: I reverted the code to its original so the error is visible (return at wrong point).

Comment: The `Sort` code modifies the order of the elements in the `arr` array.  There's no need for it to return anything.  The array that has been passed in has been sorted.  The function `Sort` should be a void function.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I disagree and discourage `#define`s and duplicating knowledge (looping until `MAXBAT` duplicates knowledge that the array size is `MAXBAT`). Just use `int BAT[40]` and then properly get the array size with `sizeof(BAT)/sizeof(BAT[0])`. If that code is too long for you, then consider writing a macro for that.

Comment: Ok thanks its always the simple stuff that'll trip you. I cant believe I didn't see that return was in the for loop

Comment: @WernerHenze - I really cannot see why. When you have 500 or 5000 lines of code, Having to pick through each array definition and loop definition to change the size of a constant makes no sense and magnifies the risk of human induced copy error by 100% by every constant you must change. Further if you have *magic numbers* of `40`, `240`, `408` sprinkled through your code, you cannot do a simple find/replace. *magic-numbers* are just bad practice. The only times raw numbers should appear in your code are where mandatory like `fscanf` *field-width* modifiers, etc. that cannot be defined.

Answer (score 2):

Your sort routine should have worked as written, but you are failing to enable warnings in your code and thus you are not allowing the compiler to help you fix the warnings and errors in your code -- that alone would have allowed your code to run just fine.

For instance, your compiler will tell you the exact line number, and many times the exact character in that line where the error or warning was detected, e.g.

```
bubblesortfn.c: In function ‘Sort’:
bubblesortfn.c:21:5: warning: return makes integer from pointer without a cast 
[enabled by default]
     return arr;
     ^
```

How can a return make an integer from a pointer?? Simple, you have your function attempting to return an integer array (`int *`), and you have your function declared `int Sort`. (you don't need to return anything, but you can simply fix it by changing your declaration to `int *Sort (....)`).

The remainder of the problems are simple syntax issues and unused variables (e.g. `a` in `main()`) that would be instantly flagged by your compiler -- listen to it. Let it help you write better code.

Always compile with *warnings enabled*, and **do not** accept code until it *compiles cleanly without warning*. To enable warnings add `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` to your `gcc/clang` compile string. For `clang`, instead you can use `-Weverything`. For **VS** (`cl.exe` on windows), use `/W3` (or use `/Wall` but you will get quite a few extraneous non-code related warnings). Read and understand each warning -- then go fix it.

As mentioned in my comment, don't use *magic numbers* in your code (except where absolutely required like with the `fscanf` *field-width* modifier). Instead, If you need a constant, `#define` one (or more), or use a global `enum` to do the same thing. That way you have one single place at the top of your code to change things if needed and you don't have to go picking through your declarations or loop limits to change things.

Literally, fixing the warnings identified and tidying things up a bit was all that was needed to get your code working and properly sorting the array in your `Sort` function (I also added a `prnintarray()` function to print your array to avoid the repeated loops in `main().` Putting it altogether, and seeding the random number generator by calling `srand()` before you use `rand()`, you could do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

/* if you need a constant, define one (or more) - avoid magic numbers */
#define ROWSZ   10      /* max integers to print per-row */
#define MAXB    40      /* max integers in BAT */
#define MULTP  599      /* multiplier constant */

int *Sort (int arr[], int size)
{
    int i, j, a;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (j = i + 1; j < size; j++) {
            if (arr[i] > arr[j]){
                a = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = a;
            }
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

/* simple print function to output arr of sz with rowsz int per-row */
void prnintarray (int *arr, size_t sz, size_t rowsz)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
        if (i && i % rowsz == 0)
            putchar ('\n');
        printf (" %4d", arr[i]);
    }
    putchar ('\n');
}

int main (void) {

    int BAT[MAXB] = {0};    /* initialize all arrays - good practice */

    srand (time(NULL));     /* seed the random number generator */

    for (int i = 0; i < MAXB; i++)      /* fill array */
        BAT[i] = MULTP * ( (float)rand() / (float)RAND_MAX );

    puts ("\nunsorted array:\n");
    prnintarray (BAT, MAXB, ROWSZ); 

    Sort (BAT, MAXB);

    puts ("\nsorted array:\n");
    prnintarray (BAT, MAXB, ROWSZ); 
}
```

**Example Use/OUtput**

```
$ ./bin/bubblesortfn

unsorted array:

  461  519  346  508  265   93  358  407  278  151
  465  531  430  148  181  227  452  206  401  202
  103  518  259  267  342  495  570  431  477  455
  164  339  375  511  248   42    6    8  450  284

sorted array:

    6    8   42   93  103  148  151  164  181  202
  206  227  248  259  265  267  278  284  339  342
  346  358  375  401  407  430  431  450  452  455
  461  465  477  495  508  511  518  519  531  570
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

**Use `qsort` For Real-World Sorting**

While there is nothing wrong with writing a bubblesort function for the learning aspect of it, the C-library provides `qsort` which can, and should, cover the majority of your sorting needs. Your only job in using `qsort` is to write a simple `compare()` function to tell `qsort` how to sort adjacent members of the array. The prototype for the `compare()` function usually sends new C programmers into a state of panic. The prototype is:

```
int compare (const void *a, const void *b)
```

Don't let it bother you. `a` and `b` are just pointers to the two members of your array currently being compared. Your job is to write the remainder of the function so that if the value pointed to by `a`:

- sorts before the value pointed to by `b`, a negative number is returned;
- is equal to the value pointed to by `b`, zero is returned and finally
- sorts after `b` a positive values is returned. (all just like `strcmp`).

To handle the fact that `a` and `b` are void pointers, you simply cast them to `int` pointers before dereferencing to make use of their values, e.g.

```
int compare (const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const int *pa = a,    /* a and b are pointers to elements being compared*/
              *pb = b;    /* in array, cast as required to proper type */
```

Since your array is `int`, `a` and `b` will be pointers-to `int`, you simply cast them to `int *`. Now you can access the values through the pointers (e.g. dereference `*pa` to get the value at the address held by `pa`).

Now to satisfy the return requirements the trivial solution would be:

```
     return *pa - *pb;
```

However, if the `*pa` is a large negative value and `*pb` is a large positive value, subtracting `*pa - *pb` can easily result in *integer overflow* and *undefined behavior*. Instead of a direct subtraction, by using two inequalities, chance of overflow can be eliminated while providing the needed return. Think through:

```
    return (*pa > *pb) - (*pa < *pb);
```

So putting your `qsort` function together and replacing your call to `Sort` with a call to `qsort`, you would rewrite your code as:

```
int compare (const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const int *pa = a,    /* a and b are pointers to elements being compared */
              *pb = b;    /* in array, cast as required to proper type */

    /*  inequality avoids overflow from subtracting 2 large values
     *  (x > y) - (x < y) , returns -1, 0, 1 (like strcmp) for 
     *  -1 -> x sorts before y,  0 -> x equals y,  1 -> x sorts after y
     */
    return (*pa > *pb) - (*pa < *pb);
}
```

Then

```
    qsort (BAT, MAXB, sizeof *BAT, compare);
```

Give it a try. As a bonus for large arrays, `qsort` will be *Orders of Magnitude* faster than a bubblesort (one of the slowest sorts for large arrays)

Comment: Thanks David as you guessed I'm about 2 days into C programming coming from java and having never really used anything but eclipse I was wondering where the warnings were when I compiled I had gotten some but not a lot of helpful one's adding those to GCC is a great tip I wish I had known

Comment: Glad to help. C is a fantastic language, but there is a lot to learn. You have absolute control over your program (and the absolute responsibility to make sure it is right - there are no training-wheels `:)` C allows you to handle memory down to the byte -- something java generally hides from you (this is also what allows C to be so blazingly fast) The best advise I can give on learning C is simply to *slow - down*. There is a lot to learn. Don't take is as a race to learn C, it's more a journey. Pay attention to the details, they are the only guardrails C provides. Good luck!